# specflow html report is not getting generated in case of system reboot

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

My system is scheduled to be rebooted at some time on weekend, if the system is rebooted while testcases are running no html report is generated.We have written the code to generate html report under hook "AfterTestRun". We are using Nunit runner to run the testcases.

I have tried finally clause as well, but its also not getting executed. Also tried overriding OnShutdown() method of System.ServiceProcess namespace, but its also not getting called(not sure I have written it under right hook).

Kindly advice.

TIA!!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the NUnit Runner is killed by the reboot. Do you reboot with shutdown /r /f ? Then you are forcing to kill all processes.

Could you not reschedule the test runs and your reboot so that they are not at the same time?